# Python Pandas - Appending to dataframe: One by One or Batch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing an app that monitors an applications scanning process. Of course to check this overtime I have to log the progress (don't ask me why this isn't in the app already).

To do this the app runs every half hour, determines what's worth loggin and not and adds them to a pandas dataframe that is then saved locally as a CSV so next run it can determine if progress is as we expect.

My question is that should I append the data i need to as I find it through the run or store it in a list or another dataframe and append it all at the end of a run before saving to CSV?

Is there a benefit to one way or another or is the difference between running append multiple times vs once negligable?

The reason I ask is this could eventually be large amounts of data being appended so building efficiencies in from the start is a good idea.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what you mean by `large amounts of data`. If it's `MB` then keeping everything as a df in memeory is fine; however if `GB` then it's better to saving them to CSV and `concat` to a new df

```
from glob import glob
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in glob('/path/to/csv_files/*.csv')])
```